# How to make image size resizable when expand the div element which hold masonary images?

Tags: html, css, angular

Here is what I tried :

### html

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background: yellow; overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
  <as-split direction="vertical">
    <as-split-area>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tiam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </p>
    </as-split-area>
    <as-split-area>
      <ngx-masonry [options]="masonryOptions">
        <div ngxMasonryItem class="masonry-item" *ngFor="let item of masonryItems">
          <img masonryLazy loading="lazy" [src]="item.img" />
        </div>
      </ngx-masonry>
    </as-split-area>
  </as-split>
</div>
```

### css

```
.masonry-item {
  width: 95px;
}

img{
  width: 90px;
}
```

**.ts** file I have set the images as array object

[Here is the stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-split-demo-bwirw1?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Now I have vertical scroll bar in the masonery items area. I want to show only two image rows. when I expand the DIV image size should be change depend on the expanded DIV height.

is it possible to do with masonery ?

Comment: Support and documentation seems lacking for that library. I wouldn't mess with trying to hack it together personally.

Comment: I thougt best way to do that is without using mesonary. I could achive that thanks. Get the height of the container and set that height to images (width will automaticly deside).

this.mySplitArea.nativeElement.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${this.value}, 1fr)
this method helped me to devid omage to two rows